# 404 on all pages other than index page after adding .htacess

Tags: magento-1.9

I wanted to remove /index.php from all Magento urls - I sought help online and found a solution within .hatacess file. There was no such file in the route of my Magento directory, so I created one with the following code -

```
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

        ############################################
        ## enable rewrites

        Options +FollowSymLinks
        RewriteEngine on

        ############################################
        ## you can put here your magento root folder
        ## path relative to web root

        RewriteBase /

        ############################################
        ## workaround for HTTP authorization
        ## in CGI environment

        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

        ############################################
        ## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

        ############################################
        ## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

        ############################################
        ## rewrite everything else to index.php

        RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

        </IfModule>
```

The url's now seem to have changed to remove the /index.php but if I go to the url I get a 404 error. If I add back in the 'index.php' into the url it works.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is Magento installed in the web server doc root or in a subdirectory? `RewriteBase` must reflect where Magento is installed, for example if in `/magento/`, then `RewriteBase /magento/`. The `.htaccess` file also needs to be in your web server doc root folder.

Comment: Hi thanks for coming back to me, all magento files are in /httpdocs/ so am I right in thinking the rewrite base of / is correct? It is not stored in a magento specific folder.

Comment: Yes, if Magento is installed in the web server doc root, then `RewriteBase /` is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I enabled the URL rewrites on my installation:

**1.** To enable the url rewrite, just turn on the Magento configuration in:

Admin > Configuration > General > Web > Search Engines optimization > Use Web Server Rewrites = Yes

**2.** Change the line `RewriteBase /` insite the .htacces file on the magento root directory if needed:

Basically, if you access your website through `http://example.com/marketplace/` then you should have `RewriteBase /marketplace/`

**3.** Enable mod_rewrite in Apache:

Edit httpd.conf and add or uncomment this line `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`.
If you are using wamp this file is in `<install directory>/bin/apache/apache<version>/conf/`

Refresh your Magento cache and try again.